# Text Mesh Pro UGUI Objects disappearing in Play Mode, Unity Version 2019.3.5fl Personal

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

So I have been stuck in this issue for awhile now: I get the error message: "Reference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" but that's because some of my text mesh pro objects gets deleted by itself!!! Apparently every single time I hit play some of the text mesh pro objects disappear from where it was assigned in the first place..

Code Implementation in the script class:
[image: Code Implementation]

Example: This is how it look before play mode:
[image: Before Playmode]

Now this is how thei nspector section looks like while on play mode:
[image: While on Play Mode]

Now once I hit play a few text mesh pro objects just got deleted by itself..
Any idea or feedback please?

Thank you in advance!
Amaury

Comment: Sounds like there is a script deleting your objects ... hard to find out for us here. In order to debug where it happens you could put this component on your TMP objects: `public class Debugger : MonoBehaviour { private void OnDestroy() { Debug.LogWarning("I just got destroyed!", this); }` then you should see in the stacktrace in which code that object was destroyed. Additionally you could ofcourse directly set a breakpoint in that line and step back through the call stack

Comment: Also .. your two Screenshots are from different scripts or at least different versions

Comment: As derHugo said, you probably destroy objects. But, maybe, instead of destroy these object you just want to disable them using {gameObject.setActive(true/false}

Comment: @derHugo thank you for your prompt response! Just updated the screenshot since I uploaded the wrong one from a testing class.

Comment: @A.Gerber I double check my script multiple times and everything seems to be legit.. just not quite sure why only those text mesh pro objects get disabled..I also just updated my post with a screenshot of my implementation

Answer (score 2):

Alright I see what is Wrong.

In the inspector, you set every Text Mesh Pro Object you need.

But in your script, you are using the function GetComponent on every of the object, which is useless and even buggy since you already declarate them in the inspector.

Remove these lines and it should work :)

EDIT: Also, for your interest, the function GetComponent will only return the first component found ATTACHED to the gameObject. But you don't have TMPText attached to your gameObject and more than that, you don't have MULTIPLE TMPText attached.

Comment: OMG!!! How I didn't see that!! Thank you much!! You're tremendously right!!! I just fixed and thank you for the helpful information. Have a great day!